# Angular HostListener triggered inside formGroup

Tags: angular

I have noticed some wired behaviour in Angular HostListener, this is the sample project link:
[sample project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistner-angular-iygjnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I have a directive, which use @HostListener to listen to click event. I applied this directive on a button.

If I put the button inside a form, it will be triggered every time I press `enter` key inside the input box.
If I move the button outside of the form, it will not be triggered.

[image]

my question is: who is triggering the click event, formGroup? how to solve it? thank you!

Comment: Button by default has type submit. Maybe try `<button myHostclick type="button">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every button is by default of  `type=submit` in a `<form>`.

So when you hit `enter`, you trigger a click on all button that are not `type="button"` .

Comment: thank you! I have been wrestling with this issue for hours